# How to extract string from string tensor using TensorFlow C API?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a string tensor created in TensorFlow C API with data type TF_Tensor*, how can I get the content of the string? I also need to use decoding?

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. What resources do you use for reference about the TensorFlow C API? Please tell, in your question, what you found there and how that is insufficient.

Comment: Hi! Have you checked this thread yet?   
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/group/string-ops  .                                                     
   please provide a sample stand-alone code to expedite the issue. Thanks!